A prime number in a sequence with number 1001
Starting with a positive integer, new numbers are generated by dropping the last digit and adding four times
this digit to the remaining number.
Example:
$183 \rightarrow 18+4*3 = 30 \rightarrow 3+4*0 = 3 \rightarrow 0+4*3 = 12 \rightarrow \dots$
If the number 1001 appears in this sequence, is it possible that there is a prime number in any position of this sequence?


 No.


 Either all elements in such a series are divisible by 13, or none are.
 If one element is divisible by 13, then next is:
 10t + u == 0 (mod 13).  (multiply both sides by 4)
 Then 40t + 4u == 0 (mod 13)
 t + 4u == 0 (mod 13)


 Similarly, if one element is divisible by 13, so was the previous:
 t + 4u == 0 (mod 13)  (multiply both sides by 10)
 10t + 40u == 0 (mod 13)
 10t + u == 0 (mod 13)


 Since 1001 is divisible by 13, all elements in the chain are divisible by 13, so the only prime that can occur is 13.  But 13 can't appear before 1001 (13 leads only to itself) or after 1001 (1001 -> 104 -> 26 -> 26).


This is based on the fact that $39$ is a multiple of $13$.  In essence we are adding $39$ times the units digit, which produces a $0$ in the units place, then dividing by $10$.  Each operation maintains the status of being a multiple of $13$.  Well done.
